# Power series solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Solve the equation

$$(1-x^2)y'' -2xy'+2y = 0$$

using power series.

Replacing with $y=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and the respective derivatives, the procedure returns the recursion formula:

$$a_{n+2}= \frac{n-1}{n+1}a_0$$

Because $a_3=0$, odd coeficients go to $0$ and for even coeficients the recursion formula ends up like this:

$$a_{2n}=\frac{a_0}{2n+1}$$

So the solution would be:

$$y(x)=a_1x+a_0\left(1-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}\right)$$

However the textbook states that the solution is:

$$y(x)=a_1x+a_0\left(1-x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right)$$

I can't see where did I go wrong, neither how can the $2n+1$ end up in the series. Any help/pointing would be appreciated

Comment: I got $a_{2n}=-\frac{1}{2n-1} a_0$ leading to textbook form after replacing n with $n+1$ so that the series can sum from $n=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
You're almost there

\begin{eqnarray}
a_2 &=& -a_0 \\
a_4 &=& \frac{1}{3}a_2 = -\frac{1}{3}a_0 \\
a_6 &=& \frac{3}{5}a_4 = -\frac{1}{5}a_0 \\
a_8 &=& \frac{5}{7}a_6 = -\frac{1}{7}a_0 \\
&\vdots&\\
a_{2n} &=& -\frac{1}{2n-1}a_0 \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

So your solution becomes

\begin{eqnarray}
y(x) &=& \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n = a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}a_n x^n \\
&=& a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_{2n} x^{2n} + \cancelto{0}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1}} \\
&=& a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_{2n} x^{2n} \\
&=& a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{2n + 2}x^{2n+2} \\
&=& a_0 + a_1 x -\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{a_0}{2n + 1}x^{2n+2} \\
&=& a_1 x + a_0 \left(1 - x\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2n + 1}x^{2n+1} \right) \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}